# i'm trying to add music to my game but it stops after

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

so i am very new to scripting and this is my first application i build followed a tutorial but now i want to add music to it found a small code online but the music stops after 1 min while music should last 7 mins?

anyone here who can help me with this?

and also how could i make a song loop?

i did get this   " MediaPlayer.setLooping(true); " but i don't know if it's gonna work so wanted to ask with this question too :p

Thanks already for you'r time.

i've looked for similar questions and used those answers but did not work, are i did implement it wrong since i am very new to this..

### My Code.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH = dm.widthPixels;
    Constants.SREEN_HEIGHT = dm.heightPixels;


    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));





    MediaPlayer Music = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music);
    Music.start();
    MediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
}
```

}

I would like music to play and continuesly looping it does not need to stop.

Comment: the way i know android youll have to move to a seconds thread to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need WakeLock or background service for playing music in sleep mode. I guess you can try keep your device alive (tap screen) and music would play.

1) Wakelock. Add permission to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And call on Create method:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);  
wakelock= pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getCanonicalName());
wakelock.acquire();
```

[docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock)

2) Background service

[docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

This is much more complicated, because you need to create notification etc. But you can try to follow android docs.

3) Read this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer). Here is guide with examples with wakelock and service.

Comment: I think i am doing something wrong app won't start now anymore :/ But thanks for the information, 

i'll try something else first and comeback on this one later.